# Como puedo hacer un programa que cree dos archivos en c# visual studio?

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber como poder crear las clases y dos archivos a su vez, que el usuario pueda elegir a cual entrar o ver:

```
public class Prueba
{
    private StreamWriter sw = null;
    private String sfileName = "Pruebas.txt";
    public String sUltimoError = "";

    public Prueba()
    {
        sw = new StreamWriter(sfileName, true);
    }

    public void CerrarArchivo()
    {
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Medio entendi tu pregunta y la solucion que se me ocurre es esta:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] filesToSelect = new string[] { "Prueba", "Otro" };
        string fileToSelectMenu = "";
        for(int i=0; i< filesToSelect.Length; i++)
        {
            var addComma = i == filesToSelect.Length -1? "" : ",";
            fileToSelectMenu += $" {filesToSelect[i]}={i+1}{addComma} ";
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"¿Qué archivo quiere utilizar? {fileToSelectMenu}");
        int archivoSeleccionado = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Archivo archivo = new Archivo(filesToSelect[archivoSeleccionado-1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            archivo.Escribir($"{ DateTime.Now : yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.f} Info: {Guid.NewGuid()}");
        }
        archivo.CerrarArchivo();

        archivo.Leer();
    }
}

public class Archivo
{
    private StreamWriter _sw;
    private readonly string _fileName;
    public string sUltimoError = "";
    private readonly string _nombre;

    public Archivo(string nombre)
    {
        _fileName =  $"{nombre}.txt";
        _sw = new StreamWriter(_fileName, true);
    }

    public void Escribir(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            _sw.WriteLine(text);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Leer() {
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_fileName);
            var line = sr.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
    }


    public void CerrarArchivo()
    {
        _sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Lo que hice es crear una sola clase para manejar cualquier archivo y despues pasarle el nombre del archivo a esa clase en base a la opcion que el usuario seleciono.